# What does the phrase “the greatest balance of happiness over unhappiness” mean?

Tags: meaning

> A utilitarian defines ‘good’ as ‘whatever brings about the greatest
> total happiness’. This is sometimes known as the Greatest Happiness
> Principle or the Principle of Utility. For a utilitarian the right
> action in any circumstances can be calculated by examining the
> probable consequences of the various possible courses of action.
> Whichever is most likely to bring about the most happiness (or at
> least the greatest balance of happiness over unhappiness) is the right
> action in those circumstances

Philosophy: The basics. Nigel Warburton

What does "the greatest balance of happiness **over** unhappiness" mean?
And I don't understand the use of "over" there. Could your explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is as [described at wiktionary,](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/over#Preposition) etymology 1, definition 2–3:

> (*in certain collocations*) As compared to.
> *Sales are down this quarter **over** last.*

The meaning is that, if an action cannot be taken that will result in pure happiness, the action to be taken should result in the best *ratio* of happiness to unhappiness (which is, not coincidentally, similar to definition 4.)

Answer (score 1):

The "over" hear means simply "compared to". So the amount of happeiness should exceed the amount of unhappiness by as much as possible.

Comment on the answer from @randomhead

In mathematics "A over B" would be the ratio or fraction A/B and the statement would mean that A/B should be as much greater than 1 as possible.

Then the quote would say the goal was to make that fraction (the "balance") as large as possible: much greater than 1.   I don't think everyday usage calls for interpreting "over" as creating a fraction. Making the difference A - B as large as possible has the same everyday meaning.